# Formula for sorting points with top and left position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, math, formula

Here I have a table and points inside table. I want to know is there some math formula for sorting this points like I draw on image.

[image]

So I have table, points (with top and left position) and I want to write function or to tell me math formula to sort this points like I draw on image... here you can see which points will be on 1. position, which on 2. position, which on 3. ... etc.

All this I have in html format but I need to know formula to write an javascript or jquery function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
function compare(a,b) {
    var rowA = Math.floor(a.y / rowWidth);
    var rowB = Math.floor(b.y / rowWidth);

    // Sort by row
    if (rowA < rowB) return -1;
    if (rowA > rowB) return 1;

    // Sort by horizontal position within a row
    return compare(a.x, b.x)
}
```

(Please excuse any syntax errors; I don't use JavaScript that often.)

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what's going on there.